# Entry Point Not Found for a application: WebDev.WebServer40.EXE -

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webpages

I tried to run the asp.net projects that are connected to the server.
but I get the alert window like this :

"WebDev.WebServer40.EXE - Entry Point Not Found"
The procedure entry point ons_subscriber_cancelcallback could not be located in the dynamic link library oraons.dll.

Previously I can run the project and never get problems like that.
How to resolve this problem?

thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my own problem. The issue is the `Oracle.DataAccess` version that i use in `References`. I remove `Oracle.DataAccess` from `References`, and add it back with the latest version.